# Из Css в SASS, возможно?

Tags: css, sass, scss

Недавно открыл для себя препроцессор SASS/ Да, он здорово облегчает жизнь вложенностью,миксинами и прочими плюшками. Но я не хочу быть всё время привязанным к нему, а использовать время от времени. В чём же проблема? Проблема в том, что при попытке записать в CSS дополнительное значение своё, оно не конвертируется в SASS, вот покажу на примере.

Вот стили заголовков H ( слева SASS, справа CSS)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я пропишу стиль font-size в SASS и сохраню, то всё прекрасно компилируется в CSS

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если я пропишу в CSS например, background-color:lime (для примера), то после сохранения не переведется все в SASS

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А мне бы хотелось чтобы тоже переводилось, более того SASS стирает стили CSS если в него что-то новое прописать

Что в настройках не так ? Программа используется Prepros для SASS. Вот  Настройки Для Style.SASS

[image]

А вот непосредственно для его величества style.css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Это в одну сторону работает. У вас есть scss исходник и css конечный результат, причем результат может быть пропущен к примеру через автопрефиксор или еще что-то он не предназначен для двухсторонней связи

Comment: Спасибо, эхх вот жеж как((( Почему то такое чувство, что разработчики не привязаны строго к препроцессору, свободны от него, или это повсеместная практика , в основном сидят на нём и почти забыли как в CSS писать?

Comment: @РусланКамов лично я сижу на postсss и пишу чистый css со всеми современными плюшками, потом в зависимости от необходимой поддержки собираю оптимизированные стили. Нативные переменные уже хорошо поддерживаются, но если надо можно их заменить статическими значениями во время сборки, в принципе все что есть на препроцессорах можно подрубить. Но это на фрилансе, где я сам себе хозяин, а вот в компаниях там обычно препроцессоры требуют.

Comment: надо наверное переходить на изучение postcss.)) Спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Если есть потребность одноразово перегнать css в sass я пользуюсь [этим](https://css2sass.herokuapp.com/) конвертером. А потом подправляю руками, выношу переменные и т.д.

Везде в основном постпроцессоры используются, да.
Лично я терпеть не могу {} и ; в стилях, поэтому всецело пишу на sass.
На прошлой работе мы использовали sass с postcss вместе. очень проперся от svg-load, например. Когда можно svg картинку подрубить прямо в стилях, и менять ей fill\stroke из стилей ) На морде она конвертилась в base64